# Is mv faster with --no-clobber?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, mv

I am about to move a lot of data from one place to another for a second time, because the first time I had no access to some subdirectories and files. I am not sure wheter the `-n`/`--no-clobber` argument will do what I want and if it wouldn't be better to just use `-f`/`--force` instead. Is `mv` faster with `-n`?

Comment: use `rsync` instead, then delete the old files

Comment: Yes, -mv has always been faster than -n when moving data from one dir to another